# Emulating netcat -e

Tags: linux, bash, system, netcat

How can I emulate `netcat -e` with a version of netcat that does not have the `-e` option ?

I need to trigger a command remotely. I can do it with netcat - without `-e`:

> #!/bin/bash
>
> netcat -l 8080 ; myCommand.sh

That would do the trick, **but** I would like to reply to the client depending on the success or failure of the command (to have a kind of REST - like interface).

How could I do that ?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you use a named pipe for this?

Answer (score 14):

```
mkfifo foo
nc -lk 2600 0<foo | /bin/bash 1>foo
```

Then just nc servername 2600 and ./script.sh

kill the client with ctrl+c

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to switch to the version of netcat that does support it. On Debian/Ubuntu IIRC correctly you should use netcat *traditional*, not netcat *openbsd*:

```
 sudo apt-get install netcat-traditional # netcat-openbsd
```

You will have the option of specifying explicitely which version you require:

```
 nc.traditional server 6767 -e myscript.sh

 nc.openbsd -l 6767
```

(*note the subtle differences in option usage*). As you can see (below) nc.traditional can be run as a standalone binary, depending on only libc and linux itself, so if you don't have installation permissions, you should be able to **just drop the standalone binary** somewhere (a filesystem with `exec` permission of course) and run it like

```
 /home/user/bin/mynetcat server 6767 -e myscript.sh
```

HTH

---

```
$ ldd `which nc.{traditional,openbsd}`

/bin/nc.traditional:
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7888000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb7709000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7889000)
/bin/nc.openbsd:
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77d0000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb76df000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb7582000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/libpcre.so.3 (0xb754c000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77d1000)
```

Comment: for the record, that is not what 'statically linked' means.

Comment: Yeah I know, which is why I spelled the dependencies out :) What would _you_ call this? 'Partially statically linked', 'Mostly statically linked', 'Standalone binary'? Hmm..., perhaps the latter wouldn't be so bad! **Edited**, thx

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like the idea of distributing my little script with a 'random binary'. Plus I need to test it on a dev machine (32bits) and to deploy on a staging server (64bits).